# Why is the conjugate direction better than the negative of gradient, when minimizing a function

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

In gradient descent we minimize a function $f(\textbf{x})$, by using the update rule:

$$\textbf{x}_{t+1} = \textbf{x}_t-\alpha\nabla f(\textbf{x}_t).$$

We also know, that at each iteration we have $$\nabla f (\textbf{x}_{t+1})^T\nabla f(\textbf{x}_t) = 0.$$

Because of this we have the zig-zag path in gradient descent. In conjugate gradient we use update rule:

$$\textbf{x}_{t+1} = \textbf{x}_t +\beta_t \textbf{d}_t, $$

where $\beta_t$ and $\textbf{d}_t$ are the coefficients and conjugate directions solved by the CG-method. Now my question is embedded in the following picture:

[image]

We can see from the image the zig-zag path and the reason for it is clear like I mentioned above, but the problem is understanding why are the conjugate directions the way they are. They look very nice in the picture, but I didn't get the motivation from the theory.

So my question is: Why does the conjugate gradient "route" have this nicer looking pattern than gradient descent? What part of the theory explains this?

Here is one reference I used: [Conjugate gradient](http://cmp.felk.cvut.cz/~alblcene/CG/CG_explained.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to try to wrap your head around this is to realize that an ideal method should aim to be "coordinate-invariant".

First, consider the simple scenario $f(x) = x^TAx$ where
$$
A = \pmatrix{1\\&2}
$$
You should find that in this case, both methods work extremely quickly, since we just have an ellipse in its standard orientation.  However, if we apply a change of coordinates $x = Tu$, we have the new function in terms of $u$
$$
f(u) = u^T(T^TAT)u
$$
Suppose our change in coordinates is something like
$$
T = \pmatrix{1&10\\0&1}
$$
You'll notice that this function is a sheared version of the original, much like the picture you have.  Note, however, that the performance of the conjugate gradient method is very easy to predict: we'll just have
$$
u_t = T^{-1}x_t
$$
this will **not** be the case with the gradient method.

Comment: This answer is not true. In the special case that $A$ is the identity, CG (and steepest descent) will finish in only one step. After your transformation $T$, however, CG will take two steps.